# How to appy Lazy Loading on the local JSON data

Tags: flutter, dart, lazy-loading

I have a local JSON file with a 1000 list. How to apply the Lazy Loading or scrollController function in the Listview.builder?

P/S: I have tried this [Flutter ListView lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508322/flutter-listview-lazy-loading), but I don't know how to modify it. For example: List items = List.generate(100, (position) => 'Hello $position'); how to change this part to the data that loaded from local JSON file?

Below is post.json file

```
{
    "Food": [
      {
        "name": "Cake",
        "id": "0001",
        "description": [
            {
                "category": "AAA",
                "Size": "Regular",
                "topping": "Chocolate with Sprinkles"
            },
            {
                "category": "AAA",
                "Size": "Small",
                "topping": "Chocolate only"
            },
            {
                "category": "BBB",
                "Size": "Regular",
                "topping": "Maple"
            },
            {
                "category": "BBB",
                "Size": "Small",
                "topping": "Blueberry"
            },
            {
                "category": "CCC",
                "Size": "Medium",
                "topping": "Strawberry"
            },
            {
                "category": "CCC",
                "Size": "small",
                "topping": "banana"
            },
            {
                ....another 1000 list
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Raised",
        "id": "0002",
        "description": ... // same structure as above
      }
    ]
}
```

Below is the Main file

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

// Load local Json file
Future<Post> getFoodList ()  async {
  final getResponse = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/post.json');
  var data = jsonDecode(getResponse);
  return Post.fromJson(data);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder<Post>(
              future: getFoodList(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  var getFoodName = snapshot.data!.food;
                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Wrap(
                      children: [
                        for (final food in getFoodName!)
                          GestureDetector(
                            child: Text(foodName.name.toString()),
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => foodDetail(food: food)));
                            },
                          ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text('Loading');
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the food detail page. As there will be a 1000 lists of food details, how do I apply lazy loading, scrollController?

```
class FoodDetail extends StatefulWidget {
    final Food food;
    const FoodDetail({super.key, required this.food});

    @override
    State<FoodDetail> createState() => _FoodDetailState();
}

class _FoodDetailState extends State<FoodDetail> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: widget.food.description!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Column(
                                children: [
                                    Text(widget.food.description![index].category.toString())
                                    Text(widget.food.description![index].topping.toString())
                                ],
                            );  
                        }
                    ),
                    ],
                  ),
            )));
  }
}
```

Comment: why would you want to do that? if you call `jsonDecode(getResponse)` then you are decoding all the data, so what's the point of implementing lazy load if you already have all the data?

Comment: Hi @pskink, instead of using jsonDecode, is there any better to do it? as I want to make the app faster and less memory. I'm still learning to code flutter, i need some guideline

Comment: use any database instead of local json, for more check https://greenrobot.org/news/flutter-databases-a-comprehensive-comparison/ or google for "flutter databases"

Comment: @pskink will take a look on it, may i know which database have better security/encryption?